# Magento Newsletter queue does not sent any email

Tags: php, magento

Magento newsletter queue does not send any email to subscribers. I saved newsletter template in queue for 2 days. But newsletters are not being sent.  What could be the problem.  After I have manually run this command "php bin/magento cron:run", it changes status "Not Sent" to "Sent" but any email is received by subscribers. How can i fix it? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these below steps:

1- Check if Magento cron is running by looking into the cron_schedule table. There should be resent records for the newsletter queue listed in the table and the status of the module execution.

2- Run cron service manually by pointing your browser to http://your.magento.url.here/cron.php

3- Enable PHP mail log: http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log

4- Check outgoing mail queue on the server with mailq command

5- Try to send all mail via external mail server by installing one of the SMTP extensions: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

6- Ensure that newsletter messages are not ending up in Spam folders.